# Guitar Chords Sample Library

Tags: guitar, sample

Can you suggest me a sample library in which I can find every Guitar Chord played on an acoustic guitar?

Even the not-so-popular ones like `D11` or `C#7#9`

if it does not exist, how do I create my samples?

Comment: *Every* chord would be thousands.it could,be a very impractical sample library. Better to just sample every guitar note and let users make their own chords to suit.

Comment: ok, so is there a library with the common ones? how do I make my own?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite a sample library, but check out the [Ample Guitar VST](http://www.amplesound.net/en/pro-pd.asp?id=1) (assuming you're using a VST compatible DAW).  There's a huge amount of flexibility in it.

Usage isn't quite the same as a normal instrument VST, as the keyboard 'keys' trigger different commands, so take the time to read the docs/manual.